# Control material design lite td height

Tags: css, material-design

I am using material design lite and try to control the height of a td using mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric by opening material.min.css and adding height:20px to the selector, did not make any diference.

```
.mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric{text-align:left; height:20px;}
```

Also try to create a new selector and apply to the columns i need, and also did not make any diference :

```
.padtd{
  height: 20px;
}
```

How can i control the height from .mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you should use the !important tag, if you want to set your own attributes.

```
.mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric {
    text-align:left !important;
    height: 20px !important;
}
```